# SASS: create name that is unique per-mixin?

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm creating a mixin called static() that is used inside another mixin to separate the static properties out into placeholders, so that those properties aren't repeated in the output every time a mixin is used. Here's how you would use it in a mixin called button(), for example:

```
@mixin button($color) {
    @include static('button') {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: .25em .5em;

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }

    background-color: $color;

    &:hover {
        background-color: mix(black, $color, 15%;
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the static() mixin:

```
@mixin static($mixin-name, $extend: true) {
    // set global $Placeholder-Selectors if it doesn't already exist
    $Placeholder-Selectors: () !global !default;

    $selector: map-get($Placeholder-Selectors, $mixin-name);

    @if $extend == true {
        @if $selector == null {
            $selector: unique-id();
            $Placeholder-Selectors: map-merge($Placeholder-Selectors, ($mixin-name: $selector)) !global;

            @at-root %#{$selector} {
                @include static($mixin-name, false) {
                    @content;
                };
            }
        }

        @extend %#{$selector};
    } @else {
        @content;
    }
}
```

The only purpose of the variable $mixin-name is to make sure the declarations of the created placeholder are not overwritten by another placeholder of the same name. ***My assumption is that*** the best way to ensure this is to use the name of the mixin itself for the $Placeholder-Selectors' key (since this will be unique to the mixin).

**Question:**

If that assumption is correct, I don't want to have to type out the name of the mixin I'm using (as in "@include static('button')")...so, in the static() mixin, is there a way to dynamically determine the name of the mixin that static() is being used inside?

**Or**, is there another way to ensure a placeholder that is unique per-mixin?

Comment: The purpose of this would be what?  You can't have recursion in mixins and mixins are not first-class (you can't pass them as arguments to other mixins).

Comment: I'm not going for recursion - essentially I just need a name that is unique per-mixin. So what makes the most sense is the actual mixin name itself. I'm trying to generalize a technique mentioned here: http://alistapart.com/article/dry-ing-out-your-sass-mixins - I can't give a more detailed explanation in a comment, and I didn't want to muddy up my question with stuff I didn't think pertinent.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Ask about the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point. Although sometimes a "solution" Y may involve a utility that is useful to have on hand for other problems. Having said that, this may not be one of those, since admittedly, this feature (being able to reference mixin name within mixin itself) likely has a small set of use cases.

Comment: There's nothing useful you could do with such a variable.  If you don't explain what you're trying to accomplish, no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: I've updated the question in an attempt to pose the actual problem - hopefully this is clear enough, as it was difficult to explain. And hopefully, the usefulness of the $mixin-name variable is now apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Sass does not have a way to get any of the names of the mixins used.

---

That said, you're over-engineering.  All you need to do is setup your extend selector outside of the mixin.

```
%common-button-styles {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .25em .5em;

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

@mixin button($color) {
    color: $color;
    @extend %common-button-styles;

    &:hover {
        background-color: mix(black, $color, 15%);
    }
}
```

If you're jumping through all of these hoops in an attempt to avoid creating duplicate extend only selectors via multiple imports, what you're looking for is called *import once*.  If you're a Compass user, 1.0 includes an extension by default that does this.  If not, a quick search will show you a few different ways of implementing such a feature.